# unix - accidentally moved everything under root to /old - Solaris 10

Tags: solaris, system-recovery

As the headline says everything or almost everything important as root under root (/) was moved to /old on a Solaris 10 machine. So now the typical fault when trying when running commands are `Cannot find /usr/lib/ld.so.1` (changed `$PATH` and also tried changing `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH_64` and `$LD_RUN_PATH` and exporting them but nothing of that seems to change the real library path). Tried pretty much yesterday to find something that might help but found nothing that will actually change the library path for Solaris 10 other than maybe `crle` but can't run that since `Cannot find /usr/lib/ld.so.1`.

Found a lot of root or /usr/bin recovery tips and so on for Linux but the that information for that regarding Solaris 10/Unix is not rife and very sparse.

Can't run `cp`, `ln`, `mkdir` or `mv` since `Cannot find /usr/lib/ld.so.1`. Can't neither log in with other sessions to the machine. Though one session is still up which can be used and that window's being stalled with `while true; do date; echo hej 1234567; done`. We've discussed the solution to use a Solaris boot CD and also a Linux dist on a USB drive. We've discussed the solution to switch the hard drive disks to another rack.

The `/.../static/.../mv` solution has been tested but it didn't work.

The commands that still can be used are (there might be more commands that can be used): `echo`, `<`, `>`, `>>`, `|`, `pwd`, `cd`.

Is there a way to create a directory or folder without `mkdir`? Is there any way to use `echo` and `>` or `echo` and `>>` to restore `/usr/lib/ld.so.1`? I know that more than `/usr/lib/ld.so.1` will probably need to be restored in order for commands to work.

Thank you very much for reading and have a very nice day =)

Comment: What command was used to move stuff under /old?

Comment: Solaris standard `mv`. Or more precisely: `shopt -s extglob; mv !(old) /old`.

Comment: What shell is running at the moment? some shells have inbuild commands

Comment: You could fix it with `ln`, if that's working.

Comment: "The /.../static/.../mv solution has been tested but it didn't work."  What happened?  Did it give a loader error?  What "didn't work" exactly?  The binaries in `static` are there for exactly this category of problems, if you don't want to boot temporary media.

Comment: As said `ln` isn't working. The error I received with `static` was that it couldn't be found. I probably moved it. Can you supply me with the `/.../static/.../mv` exact path for Solaris 10?

Comment: The current shell I'm running is bash as user root in the session still left.

Comment: The static tools are normally `/usr/sbin/static/mv` , etc.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you no longer have a shell running as root, you'll have to reboot into rescue media. Anything will do as long as it's capable of mounting the root filesystem read-write.

If you can still run commands as root, everything's copacetic. Set the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to point to the directories containing libraries used by the basic system tools. That's at least `/usr/lib` on a 32-bit Solaris, `/usr/lib/64` on a 64-bit Solaris, possibly other directories (I don't have access to Solaris 10 now to check). To run an executable, prefix it with the [runtime linker](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/817-1984/chapter3-1/index.html): `/usr/lib/ld.so.1` (for a 32-bit executable) or `/usr/lib/64/ld.so.1` (for a 64-bit executable) — now moved to `/old`. Thus you should be able to recover with something like:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/old/usr/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/old/usr/lib/ld.so.1 /old/usr/bin/mv /old/* /
```

Comment: Smart use of the loader. If the whole hierarchy wasn't moved to `/old`, my comment to Peschke own comment is valid here too. `mv` shouldn't be used but a command that preserve the existing hierarchy like `pax`, `tar` and the likes.

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience and taking time to write this. It works now running commands like `/old/usr/lib/ld.so.1 /old/usr/bin/mv` and `/old/usr/lib/ld.so.1 /old/usr/bin/cp` and so on. I'll see what I can do, now the problem is that I'm out of space but I might be able to fix that.

Comment: @propatience Too bad you and Gilles didn't considered my comments...

Comment: @jlliagre I still don't understand what you're on about with not using `mv`. The files were moved, so move them back. Why do you want to preserve the hierarchy under `/old`?

Comment: The issue is more than likely that not all the files were moved to /old. Otherwise, the OP wouldn't be struggling with `cp`. The `mv` command you suggested unsynchronized the top directories by creating bogus /xx/xx hierarchies.

Comment: @jlliagre Ah, ok. Well, yes, that would be a problem, but the question didn't give any indication that there were files left in `/`. I'd recommend `rsync -a` in that case if it's installed.

Comment: The OP wrote "everything **or almost everything important**".

Comment: and `rsync` might have filled the file system. Moreover `-a` isn't enough, should be `-aHAX` to make sure nothing is lost.

Comment: Yay GOD! I managed to move back everything with first `/old/usr/lib/ld.so.1 /old/usr/bin/mv` and `/old/usr/lib/ld.so.1 /old/usr/bin/cp` but no space so couldn't use `/old/usr/lib/ld.so.1 /old/usr/bin/cp`. And then editing `$PATH` and then folder by folder using `mv` with changed `$PATH`. Now it's all moved back so I can log in again and type df -h and everything. Thank you very much everyone. Really, great thanks to you @Gilles! Thank you StackExchange!

Comment: Setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` on Solaris has some perils if you need to set it so you can run both 32- and 64-bit executables. It'd be better to use the 32- and 64-bit specific versions of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` that are available in Solaris.  In this case:  `LD_LIBRARY_PATH_32=/old/usr/lib` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH_64=/old/usr/lib/64`.  [See the `ld.so.1` man page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-5165/ld.so.1-1.html): "Each environment variable can be specified with a _32 or _64 suffix. This makes the environment variable specific, respectively, to 32–bit or 64–bit processes."

Answer (score 16):

There is no way to create a directory or copy binary files with just shell builtin commands (although Gilles describes a smart potential workaround [in his reply](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/346642/2594)).

You best option is to boot Solaris on a external media (dvd, usb stick), mount or import the file system(s), and fix the mess with something like:

- Boot a Solaris installation disk and select to run a shell.
- Mount the old root (and all other file systems if any) under some directory like `/mnt` or `/a`. The Solaris boot disk might help you doing that when it detects existing file systems.
- put the files back to their original location with this command (assuming all is mounted under `/mnt`):

  ```
  cd /mnt/old
  find . -depth | cpio -pdlmPV@ /mnt
  ```
- Reboot your system

  ```
  init 6
  ```

If you are using ZFS and a recent snapshot exists, backing up the `/old` directory elsewhere then reverting to the last snapshot might be also an option.

Comment: Great answer. Boot into rescue USB, mount the filesystem, and then do something like `mv /mountpoint/old/* /mountpoint`

Comment: @Peschke Thanks, although blindingly running your suggested `mv` command wouldn't be my advice. The OP wrote "everything or **almost everything**". In the second case, moving will break still existing directories. I likely use a utility like `tar`, `pax`, or `cpio` to preserve the destination directory hierarchy.

Comment: Tied to the possible snapshot (ZFS or UFS), you could boot to an alternate BE if you're using live upgrade.  `lustatus`

And don't panic yet.  All the data still exists on the disk(s).

Answer (score 1):

Solaris includes static builds of basic utilities (`cp`, `ln`, `mv`, `rcp`, and `tar`) in `/usr/sbin/static` that you can use to repair any problem with the availability of `/usr/lib/ld.so.1` that prevents the use of the regular dynamically-linked `/usr/bin` versions.

There is no static `mkdir` provided, but you can use the static `ln` to symlink whatever directory contains `lib/ld.so.1` into place as `/usr` temporarily, and then use the standard `mkdir` to create whatever directories you need. You can rename directories that already exist using the static `mv`.

This goes at least as far back as Solaris 2.5.1, where I found that the stock ld.so.1 segfaults if you try to run it manually as shown in Gilles' example.