# How to use QEMU without desktop

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu

I'm trying to simulate an Ubuntu system on my Ubuntu server. This is because I need to do something dangerous and I don't want to ruin my system.

My Ubuntu server has no desktop, I just ssh on it with Putty to work.

I've downloaded the Ubuntu 16.04 iso file and here is what I've done:

```
apt install qemu-system-x86
qemu-system-x86_64 -cdrom ubuntu-16.04.3-server-amd64.iso -boot d -nographic -net user,hostfwd=tcp::44444-:22
```

Then I try to ssh on the VM like this:

```
ssh user@localhost -p 44444
```

But it will block.

[image]

Comment: You already have. If you want a connection to the VM then you'll have to run that separately.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams  Could you please check my re-edition?